# How to identify which button is clicked inside which div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have coded a `div` section which contains a button(Select Equipment).There can be many number of the same `div` containing the same button. I want to identify which button is clicked and change the status from open to complete of that particular `div` section.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pad col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert"> 
    <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h4 id="frname"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="pad col-md-5">
        <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" id="equipment" name="equipment" type="button" OnClick='change();'>Select Equipment</button></span>
        <div class="status">
            <b>Status</b>
            <i class="open" id="open">Open</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pad col-md-1">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="closee" id="garbage" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function change() {
    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
    nextTab($active);
    $("div.pen").find('.open').attr("class","complete");
    $("i.complete").html("Complete");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check my answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39290987/6608101

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```js
$('.select-eq').click(function(){
  
 $(this).parent('span').next('div.status').children('i').html("completed");
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert"> 
        <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <h4 id="frname"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="pad col-md-5">
                <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary select-eq" id="equipment" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                <div class="status">
                            <b>Status</b>
                            <i class="open" id="open">Open</i>

                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pad col-md-1">

            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="closee" id="garbage" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pad col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert"> 
        <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <h4 id="frname"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="pad col-md-5">
                <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary select-eq" id="equipment" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                <div class="status">
                            <b>Status</b>
                            <i class="open" id="open">Open</i>

                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pad col-md-1">

            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="closee" id="garbage" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="pad col-md-5">
                    <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                    <div class="status">
                                <b>Status</b>
                                <i class="open">Open</i>

                    </div>
            </div>
<div class="pad col-md-5">
                    <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                    <div class="status">
                                <b>Status</b>
                                <i class="open">Open</i>

                    </div>
            </div><div class="pad col-md-5">
                    <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                    <div class="status">
                                <b>Status</b>
                                <i class="open">Open</i>

                    </div>
            </div>

    $('[name=equipment]').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parents().siblings('div.status').find('i').html('Complete');
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uh9s5Lj0/

Answer (score 0):

Look below code hope it could help.
Here i put multiple div, on each div there are buttons.
I captured the button click and did the action on that button.

```js
function change(button) {
  //do your stuff here
  console.log(button.data("id"));
  button.parent().parent().find('i').text(' complete '+ button.data("id"));
  
  /*var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
  $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
  nextTab($active);
  $("div.pen").find('.open').attr("class", "complete");
  $("i.complete").html("Complete");*/
}
$('button.ret_but').on('click',function(){
  change($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pad col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert">
  <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h4 id="frname"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="pad col-md-5">
    <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" id="equipment"                 name="equipment" type="button" data-id="1">Select Equipment</button></span>
    <div class="status"> <b>Status</b><i class="open" id="open">Open</i>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="pad col-md-5">
    <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" id="equipment"                 name="equipment" type="button" data-id="2">Select Equipment</button></span>
    <div class="status"> <b>Status</b><i class="open" id="open">Open</i>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="pad col-md-5">
    <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" id="equipment"                 name="equipment" type="button" data-id="3">Select Equipment</button></span>
    <div class="status"> <b>Status</b><i class="open" id="open">Open</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pad col-md-1">

    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="closee" id="garbage" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the clicked section by retrieving the parent element of the clicked button. See the working solution https://jsfiddle.net/mp4o5z3u/

Snippet

```
<body>
  <div class="test">
    <button class='btn'>click me</button>
    <i class="open">Open</i>
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <button class='btn'>click me</button>
    <i class="open">Open</i>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
 var divClicked = $(this).parent();
 divClicked.find('i.open').attr('class', 'complete').html('Complete');
})
})
```